# Is CodeBlocks still relevant or should I upgrade to a new lightweight IDE?

Tags: linux, c++, ide

Just switched to Peppermint from Windows and I was wondering if there are better IDEs than CodeBlocks for a C++ programmer. I'm not saying that it sucks, but its old school vibes (and burning eye white theme) are not really for me. So I'm searching for a good IDE with:

- A Dark theme (it's not even supposed to be optional anymore)
- Good performance even with a potato PC (I'm on a 10 years old laptop, single core AMD CPU and 4GB of RAM, and performance was one of the reasons why I decided to install Peppermint in the first place)
- Code completion and file parsing support for C++ language
- Possibly user friendly
- (Optional) Active community

  Just to be clear, my ideal IDE would have Visual Studio Community look and features, but without performance problems (that's why I only have experience on CodeBlocks). I'm going to stick with CodeBlocks for the next few weeks, but I'm open for other IDEs.

Comment: For C++, stick with CodeBlocks.
You can add dark theme, you have good performance, code completion with file parsing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

CodeLite is a powerful and lightweight IDE specializing in C, C++, PHP and JavaScript. Its features include:

- Generic support for compilers (for example Clang)
- Built-in GDB support
- Database-based code completion mechanism
- Syntax highlighting for C/C++, Java, Perl, XML, Makefile, Lua, Diff files,
  PHP, JavaScript, Python, HTML, and ASP
- Text folding
- Bookmarks
- Find and Replace
- doxygen comment generator

CodeLite is in the [official Ubuntu repositories](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=codelite&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all) for all currently supported versions of Ubuntu, so it is also installable from the Peppermint OS repositories with the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install codelite
```

There won't be any learning curve with CodeLite for anyone who has experience using CodeBlocks. Also see [CodeLite IDE - Forums](https://forums.codelite.org/).

[image: CodeLite]

Comment: This looks like exactly what I was searching for, but what about its community? Is it often updated?

Comment: CodeLite is updated to the next version every 1-2 years. For more specific information about CodeLite's update schedule run this command: `rmadison codelite`. Also see [CodeLite IDE - Forums](https://forums.codelite.org/).

Answer (score 3):

From my experience, haven't coded in C++ in a while, for windows, Visual Studio takes the cake. I've been using Eclipse IDE in recent times, I would suggest it if you don't want to go for Visual Studio.

1. Eclipse can be themed, i.e a full dark theme is an option.
2. Can't really comment on performance, it works well for me, but I've got decent hardware.
3. Has code completion and file parsing support for C++.
4. I find it user friendly, but that may vary person to person.
5. It's got a active community as it supports many development environments.

I assume you'd like to use it on Linux, since your question has a linux tag. Eclipse IDE for C/C++ has linux support.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but performance is not an optional in my case. Might try later, but I'm searching for a lightweight IDE.